# :Host CSS equivalent for VueJS Templates?

Tags: css, vue.js

I tried out Angular before switching to Vue and found the `:host` selector in their components to be very handy. The jist of this is that it applies the stylings for `:host` to the component itself.

Is there an equivalent of this that works with `.vue` files in they `<style scoped></style>` section?

### Examples:

#### Using Scoped

**Parent:**

```html
<template>
  <div class="host">
      <layout-header :open-nav="openNav" @toggle-open="toggleOpen"></layout-header>
      <layout-sidebar :open-nav="openNav"></layout-sidebar>
      <layout-content></layout-content>
      <layout-footer></layout-footer>   
  </div>
</template>
```

```css
<style scoped>
  .host {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
</style>
```

**Content:**

(`<layout-content>`)

```html
  <div class="host">
    stuff
  </div>
```

```css
<style scoped>
  .host{
    flex: 1;
  }
</style>
```

**Output:**

(removing the header, footer, and sidebar for simplicities sake.)

This results in the header, sidebar, content, and footer inheriting the parents css if they have a `.host` class.

HTML:

```html
<div data-v-238e7577="" class="host">
  <div data-v-7412829c="" data-v-238e7577="" class="host">stuff</div>
</div>
```

The CSS applied to the child element:

[image]

Comment: Every Vue component has a root element (typically a `<div>`). Give it an ID and apply rules to that.

Comment: I want to avoid this, as now I would need to ensure there are no Id collisions in the components, or in any other application that uses those components. Similarly assigning it a class can have similar undesirable consequences.

I'm sure Vue has a way of doing this?

Comment: Give it a class - `.host` or something - that you won't use in the main application-level CSS file, and make your style block scoped. Should prevent any conflicts.

Comment: [Scoped CSS](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#scoped-css) prevents the collisions that you're concerned about. Applying a class to the root element of your component, and targeting that class in your CSS would be the equivalent to `:host`.

Comment: The issue is child components seem to inherit the scoped CSS of their parents. So if I have a child component and a parent with the class `.host` as an example, the child components will have the styling of the parents `.host` applied to it... Which seems a a bit off given how the docs are written?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no equivalent for Angular's `:host` in Vue.

The closest you are gonna get is by using [CSS module](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html#usage).

**Demo:** App.vue in https://codesandbox.io/s/o4orw9nz35

```
<template>
  <div id="app" :class="$style.container">
    <p class="red">p tag</p>
    <div class="blue">div tag</div>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" module>
.container :global {
  .red {
    color: red;
  }
  .blue {
    color: blue;
  }
}
</style>
```

Note how the `.container` class is used as `$style.container` as class in the root `div`.

CSS module will generate unique class name for `.container`, **making it impossible to have class name collisions.**

---

**What does `:global` do?**

CSS module transform the CSS class name into something unique by default.

for e.g. `.container` will be transformed into something like `.container_7ba5bd90` when used as `$style.container`.

To avoid this transformation on certain classes, use `:global` to wrap them.

(Explanation for `:global` can be found [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#scope).)

Comment: Is there any reason to use `scoped` instead of `module` then if I don't want child components to inherit the scoped css of their parents? Could you also add an ELI5 of :local and :global in this context?

Comment: the answer is always "it depends on how you use it", but `module` is clearly safer than `scoped`. You may see this talk by a Vue core team member for explanation https://youtu.be/DmKOhewRRHs?t=589 of why CSS module is safer.

Comment: Note that `:host` is not an Angular thing but a [CSS standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host())